# PHP Contact form submit

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I'm working on a Mail contact form and after I submit and refresh to message keep going to my email. How could I fix this? My code is below.

```
        <?php

        if (isset($_POST['contact_name']) && isset($_POST['contact_email']) && isset($_POST['contact_text'])) {
            $contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
            $contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
            $contact_text = $_POST['contact_text'];

            if (!empty($contact_name) && !empty($contact_email) && !empty($contact_text)) {

              $to = 'test@hotmail.nl';
              $subject = 'Contact form';
              $body = $contact_name."\n".$contact_text;
              $headers = 'From: '.$contact_email;

              if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
                Echo 'Thanks for contacting me. I will be in touch soon.';
              } else {
                echo 'Sorry, an error occurred. Please try again later.';
              }

            } else {
              echo 'All fields are required';
            }
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: sessions and tokens and redirect and revalidate form. Can't beat that combo.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prevent a situation, where user resubmits the form by refreshing your page, a good choice is to **redirect** user to exactly the same page. This way last request in browser history is changed from POST to GET, and following refreshes simply reload the page without form resubmission.

This can be achieved with the following code:

```
        header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily");           
        header("Location: the-url-of-the-page.php", true, 302);
        header("Connection: close");
        exit();
```

Please make sure the code is executed after processing the form (sending e-mail) but before sending any data to the browser.

Comment: what would be default redirection code for header? I guess that is 302 by default.

Comment: yes, it is 302 by default, but 1) I never trust PHP changing from version to version 2) I see it clearly every time I see the code and do not need to consult the documentation to remember.

Answer (score 1):

You should redirect user to another page after processing form & sending email.

To redirect, you can use:

```
header("Location:thanks.php");
exit();
```

Your code should be changed to:

```
  if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
       header("Location:thanks.php"); //<-- Note change here
       exit();
  } else {
       echo 'Sorry, an error occurred. Please try again later.';
  }
```

Comment: Where in my code must I add this?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, in the if branch where you issue the mail and thank the user, you can unset the post vars as below,

```
unset($_POST['contact_name']);
```